# how to get Git second parameter in hooks script

Tags: git

How to get remote branch name in git push hooks? For example:

```
git push company-internal v1_xiaoqiang
```

When i get second parameter in pre-push hooks script:

```
echo "second parameter:$2"
```

the output is:

```
https://gitlab.hldata.com/backend/system.git
```

but I want to get the branch name: *v1_xiaoqiang*.

Because i want to avoid v1_xiaoqiang push to diffrent uncompatible branch. Like this:

```
if(local_branch_name != remote_branch_name){
    /*
    you can't push local branch v1_xiaoqiang 
    to remote branch v2_xiaoqiang because it is uncompatible
    */
}else{
     //push success...
}
```

How to get remote branch name or implement the feature? Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

From default pre-push hook :

```
# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If pushing without using a named remote those arguments will be equal.
#
# Information about the commits which are being pushed is supplied as lines to
# the standard input in the form:
#
#   <local ref> <local sha1> <remote ref> <remote sha1>
#
# This sample shows how to prevent push of commits where the log message starts
# with "WIP" (work in progress).

remote="$1"
url="$2"

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
```

If you read the description, what you have to use is :

> $local_ref $local_sha1 $remote_ref $remote_sha1

to obtain the SHA and local and remote refs.

Apart from this, doing the development on one branch (after checking out that branch) and pushing to another is highly unlikely unless if another branch is brand new.